# I have JAVA_HOME set in the necessary environments, but a VScode plugin does not recognize it

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio-code, java-home

I have JAVA_HOME set in the necessary system environments, but the VScode plugin IBM Z Open Editor gives me this error:

Your "JAVA_HOME" environment variable does not specify a valid file path. Please verify that (1) The path does not end in "/bin/java". (2) The path points to a 64-Bit Java. (3) The path points to the correct location in the file system.

[image: Here is an image of where I have JAVA_HOME declared]

(From what I can see) I have all three of these points the error is pointing to. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Type `java --version` in Command Prompt to check if you installed **JDK11 or recent version, also 64-Bit**. If not, reinstall the correct one:

> **Reference:**
>
> [Installing a Java Development Kit (JDK)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_installing-a-java-development-kit-jdk)
>
> [To Install the JDK Software and Set JAVA_HOME on a Windows System](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

The settings about JAVA_HOME in VS Code should be:

```
"java.home": "C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\AdoptOpenJDK",
```

Which you can also configure it by opening Command Palette(Ctrl+Shift+P) then choosing the option: **Java: Configure Java Runtime**

[image]

The installed JDK which is JDK11 or recent version should be displayed in the list and you can choose the one you wanted, which is equal to manually setting `java.home` in Settings.json.

If you can't see the installed jdk in the list, turn to the referenced link to check if JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables is set correctly.